# Chrome not accepting US international with dead keys keyboard 14.04

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, google-chrome, keyboard-layout, input-language

Using 14.04 with keyboard selected as 'US international with dead keys' as my keyboard layout option, (so that I may use characters from other languages) and the system accepts text input as you would expect.

Chrome however fails to recognise what keyboard I have set in system settings, no dead key input is detected or used by Chrome at all, frustratingly.

I updated from M34 to Version 36.0.1985.125 to no avail :(

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=363037 ...possibly

Comment: similar, probably related öQüÜ also don't work for me :(

Comment: Seem this issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=360388 is closely related, going to install M34 and give that a try.

Comment: Well, that didn't work at all

Comment: Try M35 (Chrome; Ubuntu's M35 will be, hopefully, out in a week or so); M34 Aura is known to be buggy. As for the issue I posted, it seems that has been fixed in M37.

Comment: Just to add, I have M37 in [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-dev).

Comment: Updated to Version 36.0.1985.125, no luck :(

Comment: Still broken, does nobody use international keyboard apart from me?

Answer (score 0):

Here a late solution (that worked at least for me)

Open terminal in your home directory. Open the file .xinputrc (you should have one) and comment the line:

`run_im xim`

Reboot your computer, and now you (hopefully) the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem because I selected "Generic 150-key (Intl) PC" as my Keyboard model.

- Goto settings-->keyboard
- Goto tab "Layout"
- Uncheck "Use system defaults"
- Choose Keyboard model "**Generic 104-key PC**"
- Choose Keyboard layout "**English (US, international with dead keys)**"

It works now, look: äüïíì. The Euro sign (€) is available with the combination <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>. You may have to log-out and in again to apply the settings.