# Greek dead key ; stopped working

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Hello I am using Xubuntu and I added the Greek keyboard layout, everything was working ok until the next restart where the accents were not working ( ; key + vowel ). 
I tried removing the layout and adding, I more or less tried all the greek layouts and no one is working correct.. 
When I press the ; key and then the letter to put the accent to it doesn't write the next character but it doesn't write the letter with the accent either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem because I selected "Generic 150-key (Intl) PC" as my Keyboard model.

- Goto settings-->keyboard
- Goto tab "Layout"
- Uncheck "Use system defaults"
- Choose Keyboard model "**Generic 104-key PC**"
- Choose Keyboard layout "**English (US, international with dead keys)**"

It works now, look: äüïíì. The Euro sign (€) is available with the combination "Alt Gr + 5". You may have to log-out and in again to apply the settings.

(Quoted myself from [Chrome not accepting US international with dead keys keyboard 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476526/chrome-not-accepting-us-international-with-dead-keys-keyboard-14-04/612823#612823))